# PlotBars procedure in Pascal for Bubble Sort algorithm

Tags: pascal

I am currently working on a program in Pascal in which I want to implement the Bubble Sort algorithm and display it visually using Bars. I have successfully written the BubbleSort procedure but I'm stuck on the PlotBars procedure (The procedure which draws bars for the BubbleSort procedure) . Now when I run the program it displays the number panel on the right and when I click the "Sort!" button it just displays only one bar and if I keep pressing the sort button it decreases the height of the bar. I am attaching below my code snippet and my outputs and also I am attaching below what I want my output to look like. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Regards,
Waleed

Code of PltoBars

```
procedure PlotBars(var data: array of Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
  yAxis: Integer;
  newWidth: Single;
  newHeight: Single;
  roundNewWidth: Integer;
  roundNewHeight: Integer;
begin
  yAxis := 600; //Screenheight is 600
  newWidth := ((ScreenWidth() - PanelWidth('NumberPanel')) / 25); // There are 25 index in array
  for i:= 0 to High(data) do
  begin
    newHeight := data[i] - ScreenHeight();
    roundNewWidth := Round(newWidth);
    roundNewHeight := Round(newHeight);
    ClearScreen();
    FillRectangle(ColorRed, i, yAxis, roundNewWidth, roundNewHeight);
  end;
end;
```

[What my Output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o1dN.png)

[What i want my Output to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fADz.png)

Comment: Code should be inserted into the question as text, not as an image. Also, what version of Pascal do you use?

Comment: You should provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your part of code does not compile, since many variables and functions are not included.

Answer (score 0):

You clear the screen inside your `for i` loop before drawing each bar, so only the last bar survives. Put the call to `ClearScreen()` before the loop (and the calls to `DrawInterface()` and `RefreshScreen()` after the loop).

Comment: Okay i did that but still only one bar appears on screen. I want my output to look like the pic i attached above. Shouldn't there be more FillRectangle procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how You draw the rectangels.
I assume Your procedure FillRectangle calls FillRect.
FillRect starts drawing from the left top corner and needs 4 coordinates[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AmiH.png)

So Your code has to look something like this:

```
procedure PlotBars(var data: array of Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
  yAxis: Integer;
  newWidth: Single;
  newHeight: Single;
  roundNewWidth: Integer;
  roundNewHeight: Integer;
begin
  yAxis := 600; //Screenheight is 600
  newWidth := ((ScreenWidth() - PanelWidth('NumberPanel')) / High(data)); // changed from fixed value, since there could be more than 25!
  roundNewWidth := Round(newWidth);

  for i:= 0 to High(data) do
  begin
    newHeight := ScreenHeight() - data[i];
    roundNewHeight := Round(newHeight);
    FillRectangle(ColorRed, i*roundNewWidth, yAxis, i*roundNewWidth+roundNewWidth, roundnewHeight);
  end;
end;
```